# Normal subgroup $N$ of a p-group $G$ intersects $Z(G)$ nontrivially; What is wrong with the following trivial argument?

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups, p-groups

I'm trying to show that a normal subgroup $N$ of a p-group $G$ intersects $Z(G)$ nontrivially (please don't tell how to show it), but it seem it is quite a trivial question considering the following argument:

> Consider $Z(N)$, a nontrivial subgroup of $N$. Since any element in
>   $Z(G)$ also commutes with the elements of $N$, $Z(G) \subseteq Z(N)$,
>   but we know that $Z(N) \leq N$, so $ \{e\} \not = Z(G) \subseteq N.$

If the answer was this, I don't think my Algebra professor would ask it, so what is wrong with the above argument ?

Comment: It's certainly not the case that $Z(G)\subseteq Z(N)$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Why ?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown By definition, any element that commutes with all the elements in the group shouldn't commute with the elements in the subgroup ?

Comment: What if $N$ is a proper subgroup of $Z(G)$?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown In that case, the statement $Z(G) \subseteq Z(N)$ would be wrong, but $N \cap Z(G) = N$, and this would agree with what I'm actually trying to show, so if I assume that $N \not \subseteq Z(G)$, then $Z(G) \subseteq Z(N$ should work ?

Comment: An element $g$ of $G$ belongs to $Z(N)$ if and only if it commutes with all the elements of $N$ and it belongs to $N$. If the latter condition is not verified you only know that  $g \in C_G(N)$ which is in general bigger than $Z(N)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$Z(N)$ and $Z(G)$ need not be at all related. If $N$ is abelian, then $Z(N) =N$, but the center of $G$ might intersect $N$ trivially. For example, the center of $S_3\times \mathbb Z_3$ intersects a subgroup of order $2$ in the first factor trivially.

In general, $Z(G) $ is a subgroup of the *centralizer* of $N$, but not necessarily the center.

Comment: In my notation, $Z(G):= C(G)$.

Comment: @onur Yes, but $Z(N) \neq C(N) $ in general, unless you're using highly unusual notation.

Comment: what is $Z(N)$ in your notation ?

Comment: @onur The set of all elements of $N$ that commute with every element of $N$. $C(N) $ is the set of all elements of $G$ that commute with every element of $N$.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks both for the answer and the replies.

Comment: @onur You're welcome.